# Is there a way to restrict file types on a file field, using AGX tagged values?

Tags: plone

Using argo uml and archgenxml, I have a file field. I would like to restrict it to one extension: .ttf

Can I do this using a tagged value?
Also is there a glossary for the AGXProfile which would answer this?

Answer (score 2):

You could try the `allowable_content_types` mime type property of `FileField|ImageField`s but I can't find anything that indicates that validation is done on that property.  IOW, this wouldn't show the user an error if they uploaded something else.  If you want that, you're going to have to write an AT field validator yourself that takes the file and validates it against the `mimetype_registry`.